# more justification for the impact scores used by the national vulnerability database

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, known-vulnerabilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why CVSS give a score of 0.66 for a full impact on CIA?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15830/why-cvss-give-a-score-of-0-66-for-a-full-impact-on-cia)

Good day ;

the CVSS attributes the following impact values ​​for confidentiality, integrity and availability:

none :           0.0 
partial impact : 0.275
complete:        0.660

I want to know what exactly 0.66 means ? Is the impact score defines a percentage ?

why not assign a value of 1 for a full impact.

Would somebody possesses a solid argument of theses scores?

thank you.

Comment: i want to have more information

Comment: I'd say if you want more information on the exact same topic/question ask for it in the same question, or comment on the answer you got last time asking him to go into further detail.

Comment: Mely - this is the same question. If you want more info, please do as Peanut suggested and let us know on the existing question what it is you need.